User creation with email and password when OTP verification
How do I create an user account with Email and password whenever OTP is verified in Firebase authentication? I have provided the code snippet in which I tried to create user with email and password.please provide me solution
private fun signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(
    credential: PhoneAuthCredential,
    name: String,
    email: String,
    number: String,
    password:String
) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(requireActivity()) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
               // mAuth.currentUser?.verifyBeforeUpdateEmail(email)
                homeViewModel.setUserData(mAuth.currentUser?.uid.toString(),name,email,number)
                //PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential()
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                val intent = Intent(requireActivity(), HomeActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "OTP is invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
}


The built-in email+password sign-in provider for Firebase does not use an OTP, but you can set up multi-factor authentication (MFA) separately.
If you want to use MFA with Firebase, follow the documentation to set it up with SMS or with TOTP.
